# Encoding issue: £ pound symbol appearing as <?> symbol

Tags: database, encoding, utf-8, character

My database field is set to utf8_general_ci and my websites encoding is utf8.

The £ symbol is coming up as a black diamond with a question mark through the center.

I tried changing it to `&pound;` in the database and it just outputted £

I tried a string replace:

```
  $row['Information'] = str_replace("£", "&pound;", $row['Information']);
```

Nothing seems to work, any ideas?

Comment: What encoding has your script file?

Comment: thes script file is utf-8, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I tried changing it to `&pound;` in the database

Don't. The database should contain raw text, never HTML-encoded content. The time to HTML-encode (using `htmlspecialchars()`) is when you insert some raw text into HTML at the output templating stage, and not before. Even if you got this to work, you'd only have fixed one character; the other 107025 non-ASCII characters would still break.

Clearly there is a mismatch of encodings here; you must ensure you use the same encoding (preferably UTF-8) everywhere, in particular:

- the encoding you've saved the PHP file in, if it contains any non-ASCII characters;
- the charset declared on the output page (by Content-Type `<meta>` or `header()`, preferably both; if you only use a `<meta>` to set it and the server is incorrectly configured it may set its own `charset` overriding yours);
- the encoding of the column in the database (each column has its own collation, so just setting it on the table is ineffective);
- the encoding used by PHP to talk to MySQL. This should be set using `mysql_set_charset`.

Unfortunately, none of these settings default to UTF-8.

Comment: using mysql_set_charset fixed it- i had never heard of this. I have also cleaned up my database back to the raw text as you suggested thanks

Answer (score 1):

Before communicating with your database, you need to send the query :

```
SET NAMES 'UTF-8'
```

It tells the database to use utf8 encoding for all queries on this connection.