# assistance with using the £ symbol in php echo

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Encoding issue: £ pound symbol appearing as <?> symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716178/encoding-issue-pound-symbol-appearing-as-symbol)

I am doing some basic echo statements and when i use echo "£" it puts a capital A before the pound sign any ideas why?

```
 echo ("£"):

 output = A£
```

the A has a symbol above.

Comment: You have an encoding issue. It's probably not actually `A`, but `Ã` (IIRC), which smells of UTF-16 being interpreted as ASCII.

Comment: @CarrieKendall, that looks like a MySQL-specific encoding issue. I'm sure there's a duplicate somewhere, but it's awfully difficult for the OP to know what to look for if he doesn't know about character encodings.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I see it as `Â£`.

Comment: [What is a character encoding, and why should I care?](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-what-is-encoding)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to do this pragmatically:

```
<?php
echo chr(163);
printf("%c", 163);
echo "&pound;"; //preferred for HTML
?>
```

Another way to do this more "manually" would be to save your files in UTF-8 encoding.

See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php) for more information.

Here's a screenshot of the results:

[image: results]

As stated by primatology, if you're going to be ouputting to HTML, make sure to include the proper encoding header for HTML. This should be inserted between your `<head>` tags.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: Your first two suggestions are broken, as they assume a certain encoding on the client-side. And "more prefered" is not valid English.

Comment: if i use echo "&pound"; it should output a £?

Comment: @andrewjackson: You're watching it "work" in one very specific scenario, with no regard for the many, many other potential cases. As I said, you've assumed a certain encoding, and then gone on to only test with that encoding. It's not an encoding-agnostic solution. It's not a robust solution. `&pound;` is your best bet.

Comment: well, yes... choose just one method

Comment: @andrewjackson: Thank you for your well-formed question. Unfortunately, it gives me no idea what part of my comments you have failed to understand. Perhaps you do not realise that a mapping of `163` to the UK Pound Symbol is encoding-defined? Best of luck in the future.

Comment: @mitchnufc yes, that is the preferred method for outputting to HTML.

Comment: Despite the ease of this solution, I wouldn't recommend it. [You should avoid entities](http://stackoverflow.com/a/436637/1122351) unless you are escaping "<", ">", or "&". (Using the actual symbol is much more user-friendly.) You have an encoding issue *somewhere*; best to solve the problem now.

Comment: @primatology: Your hint is misleading, because if you use HTML, you just want to use the default encoding which *is not UTF-8*. Also please don't stress users into UTF-8 if you can't give a guidline of pros and cons. I better suggest the W3C resources in that case, e.g. [What is a character encoding, and why should I care?](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-what-is-encoding)

Comment: @hakre, then let me point you to a W3C resource: [Which character encoding should I use for my content, and how do I apply it to my content?](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-choosing-encodings#answer). The HTML5 spec recommends UTF-8 and discourages users from any other character encoding. Thus I maintain my recommendation. Granted, perhaps a little more explanation is in order. But for a beginner, "use UTF-8 and use symbols, not named entities" is usually much less confusing than trying to grok character encodings.

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> especially helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You have to encode the php file as UTF-8 or use

```
&pound;
```

Comment: How do I encode the php file? the $ symbol works fine

Comment: Which editor do you use? In notepad.exe you can encode the file in the save dialog.

Comment: @JulianHinderer: You then have to choose the correct encoding in every component that touches the data on its way to the user's eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your HTML page is marked as UTF-8 (unicode charset). For bulletproof support, place this in your `head`:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

You should also save the file with a UTF-8 encoding—most text editors have a built-in capability for this.

---

If on Apache, you can also send the UTF-8 encoding in the `Content-Type` header by adding this to a `.htaccess`:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

Comment: I have that in the head of my html files as standard

Comment: Note that `<meta charset="utf-8">` is an HTML5 meta tag, some older browsers may only recognise the old `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` tag.

Comment: @mitcnufc, then you've got an encoding issue somewhere along the pipeline. Check to make sure the file is actually *saved* as UTF-8, and inspect the headers (using Firebug or Safari's Dev Tools) to see if your server's overriding the meta tag.

Comment: Actually, @Neil, I think support is [universal](http://web.archive.org/web/20090214110633/http://code.google.com/p/doctype/wiki/MetaCharsetAttribute), and that's a few years out of date now. But the old tag is certainly worth a shot.